# How to group by foreign keys and also retrieve other column values in laravel eloquent

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do the following query:

```
return Book::select('id', 'title', 'author_id')->groupBy('author_id')->get();
```

And it returns

> Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "book.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: What are you actually trying to retrieve? Books where same authors are listed next to each other?

Comment: nope, only the latest books by each author. Btw, it is a pseudo code.

Comment: It's not pseudo-code, it's valid code that's not working. Try writing a SELECT statement directly against your database (MySQLWorkBench) to understand what SQL you need, then figure out how to make Eloquent generate that SQL.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What criterion you want to define what is a "latest" book? Last one? A date?

Comment: postgreSQL, by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to run such query with PostgreSQL, as it requires all fields that are specified in **SELECT** list to be part of the **GROUP BY** expression.

You can read the rationale behind it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY

Comment: It's not entirely impossible if the column you group by is a primary key of the table.

Comment: But then, if you group by primary key, you just fetch all records with no grouping, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the query you wrote...it will work with other databases like Mysql and sqlite with no problem... 
The problem is your crud fundamental for postgreSQL is not clear

For Mysql : it will get any one row for one author and get author_id column and for other two column ( id and title) fetch any random value from rows matching author..

But for postgreSQL this is not the case,

Documentation for postgreSQL stats , Any and all column that is being referenced inside select clause must be used inside group by clause and only exception being if you use column name inside aggregate function like min, max .etc , you need to mention that column name in group by clause

And hence your error

Comment: I thought since I was using Eloquent perhaps Laravel should have abstracted that. Anyway, I have to study postgreSQL.

Comment: Laravel can't do that for two reason..1.group by conditions are part of business logic 2. Sequence of group by can drastically change your output.. Hence i don't think eloquent should do it internally

Comment: Consequently, the `Collection` class does have a `groupBy` method which maybe the OP can use.

Comment: It might work in MySQL - but only because MySQL doesn't reject invalid SQL and rather returns random results when the `GROUP BY` is used incorrectly.

Comment: For MySQL , it is not an invalid sql statement..i would rather say, it is an incomplete sql statement..and as i mentioned it will work with no error..but for other two column( one not in group by) value will be random from result subset for each group by match

Comment: It's not "invalid" for MySQL but it's invalid SQL as per the SQL standard.